# Json Endpoint not digested by other systems

Tags: meteor, ngrok

My json end point works perfectly when request on browser , it display raw json .
but when i use other systems such as zappier , it doesn't digest my json well .
I'm using Ngrok to tunnel with my localhost , and here what i get on ngrok dashboard.
[image]

does it have to do with some kind of compression ?

Comment: If you used iron router for those routes no compression is invovled

Comment: you are not providing enough detail to answer your question. From the tag I'm assuming your json endpoint is written in meteor? If so, then show that code please. Also, what are you actually trying to accomplish? read your json in zappier? what does curl give you? can you show your json and also show what zappier is receiving instead?